# Boost::FileSystem Linking Problem

Tags: c++, boost, linker

I downloaded and built the boost libraries (version 1.47.0) on Windows 7 (64bit) following the [instructions here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#or-simplified-build-from-source).

Now when I want to use the `Boost::Filesystem` library I can include the header file without issue and it compiles my code file. The problem arises at linking. I get the following errors;

```
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::filesystem3::file_status __cdecl boost::filesystem3::detail::status(class boost::filesystem3::path const &,class boost::system::error_code *)" (?status@detail@filesystem3@boost@@YA?AVfile_status@23@AEBVpath@23@PEAVerror_code@system@3@@Z) referenced in function "bool __cdecl boost::filesystem3::exists(class boost::filesystem3::path const &)" (?exists@filesystem3@boost@@YA_NAEBVpath@12@@Z)
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: static class std::codecvt<wchar_t,char,int> const * & __cdecl boost::filesystem3::path::wchar_t_codecvt_facet(void)" (?wchar_t_codecvt_facet@path@filesystem3@boost@@CAAEAPEBV?$codecvt@_WDH@std@@XZ) referenced in function "public: static class std::codecvt<wchar_t,char,int> const & __cdecl boost::filesystem3::path::codecvt(void)" (?codecvt@path@filesystem3@boost@@SAAEBV?$codecvt@_WDH@std@@XZ)
```

(amongst others)

It might be worth noting that when I first tried to build the project it said it couldn't find the .lib file `libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_47.lib`. I hadn't specifically told it it needed that file so not sure how it figured that out? Either way I pointed the linker to the correct directory and then it gave the above errors.

Does anybody know how to fix this problem? Thanks.

**Edit:** I'm using VS2010 toolchain through eclipse CDT to build the system. The complete compile command is

```
cl /c /EHs /MD /Zi /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include" /I"C:\boost_1_47_0" /nologo <SOURCE_FILE>
```

and the linker command

```
link /debug /nologo /libpath:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib\amd64 /libpath:C:\boost_1_47_0\stage\lib /libpath:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib\x64 /OUT:<EXE_NAME> <OBJECT_FILES>
```

Comment: Can you show code of a minimal example that reproduces the error you have?

Comment: What is your project target system? Did you build Boost with the same bitness: 32 bit for Win32, 64 bit for x64?

Comment: As for your side question, boost automatically adds a `pragma` statement to tell the linker it needs the said .lib

Comment: Regarding the "how it figured that out" part:  the Boost header files include support for auto linking on the Windows platform. The exact library name is assembled from various pre-processor defines, and then used in a `#pragma comment( lib, ... )` directive.

Comment: I used the "simplified build from source", i.e. `boostrap; .\b2` command detailed in the link. It's more than likely this could have compiled the wrong version. Sorry should have said, using VS2010, have added details to the Q.

Comment: Looking at your command line, I see that you are trying to build 64 bit project. Again, did you build Boost for 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Another option is to try and build your project using the pre-built boost libraries which you can download and install from here: http://www.boostpro.com/download/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rebuild the Boost library with address-model=64 b2 command line switch. This builds 64 bit libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on linux and happen upon this article looking for the fix the fix is (at least on ubuntu 12.10) to install the development package for boost filesystem:

sudo apt-get install libboost-filesystem-dev

That installs the correct libraries for linking to and all works well.